# Missing some records and found duplicate records wrote to output .csv file

Tags: spring-batch, spring-data-mongodb

I am using MonoItemReader and writing my .csv file but I found some duplicated records and  missing records from my .csv files
[My .csv output file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyUS1.png)

I set BatchApplication.java right this

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class BatchApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BatchApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My job and step configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Slf4j
public class BatchConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "testMongoTemplate")
    private MongoTemplate MongoTemplate;
    @Autowired
    private BatchProperties batchProperties;
    @Autowired
    private MyJobListener myJobListener;
    @Autowired
    private BatchHelperService batchHelperService;
    @Autowired
    private RecordProcessor recordProcessor;
    @Autowired
    private S3Client s3Client;
    @Autowired
    private S3Processor s3Processor;
    @Autowired
    private ReportFileWriter reportFileWriter;


    @StepScope
    public MongoItemReader<AppModel> readerOffering(final long startDateTimeEpoch, final long endDateTimeEpoch) {

        final MongoItemReader<InsuranceAppModel> reader = new MongoItemReader<>();
        reader.setTemplate(mongoTemplate);
        reader.setSort(Map.of("lastUpdatedDateTime", Sort.Direction.ASC));
        reader.setTargetType(AppModel.class);
        reader.setCollection("my_table");
        reader.setQuery("{'lastUpdatedDateTime' : { '$gte' : " + startDateTimeEpoch + ", '$lte' : " + endDateTimeEpoch + "}}");
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public Job applicationReportJob() throws Exception {

        final List<Step> stepList = new ArrayList<>();


        stepList.add(stepBuilderFactory.get("step_1_query_db").<AppModel, CSVReport>chunk(1)
                .reader(readerOffering(1698858000000L, 1698944399000L))
                .processor(recordProcessor)
                .writer(reportFileWriter)
                .build());
        stepList.add(stepBuilderFactory.get("step_2_upload_to_S3").tasklet(s3Processor).build());


        final SimpleJobBuilder jobBuilder = jobBuilderFactory.get("applicationReportJob").listener(myjobListener).incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).start(stepList.get(0));
        stepList.remove(0);
        for (final Step step : stepList) {
            jobBuilder.next(step);
        }
        return jobBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

My RecordProcessor

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class RecordProcessor implements ItemProcessor<AppModel, CSVReport> {

    @Autowired
    private BatchProperties batchProperties;

    @Override
    public CSVReport process(final AppModel record) throws Exception {
        CSVReport.CSVReportBuilder recordCsv = CSVReport.builder();
        try {
            recordCsv.applicationId(record.getApplicationId());
            recordCsv.status(record.getSstatus());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new BatchException(ex.getMessage(), ex, "ERROR_WHILE_PROCESSING__DATA");
        }
        return record.build();
    }

}
```

My ReportFileWriter

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class ReportFileWriter implements ItemWriter<CSVReport> {
    @Autowired
    private BatchProperties batchProperties;
    @Autowired
    private BatchHelperService batchHelperService;
    
    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends CSVReport> items) throws Exception {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        
        for (CSVReport item : items) {
            try {
                sb.append("\n");
                sb.append(item.getApplicationId());
                sb.append("|");
                sb.append(item.getStatus());

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.error("Error while append string");
            }
        }

        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(record)) {
            try (OutputStreamWriter fileWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("output/" +  batchHelperService.getBatchProcessingModel().getFileName(), true), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
                fileWriter.write(sb.toString().replace("null", ""));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new BatchException(ex.getMessage(), ex, "ERROR_WHILE_WRITING_FILE");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

My Spring Batch version
[My Spring Batch version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z900m.png)

I would like to know why my some data duplicated and disappeared from my .csv output file even I used chunk size = 1 and how to prevent these error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not create a new `OutputStreamWriter` inside the `write` method. This should be done only once when the `ReportFileWriter` is created.

Edit: Add code example

There seems to be no need for a custom writer from what you shared, you could use the `FlatFileItemWriter` provided by Spring Batch:

```
record CSVReport(int applicationId, String status){}

@Bean
public FlatFileItemWriter<CSVReport> itemWriter() {
    return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<CSVReport>()
            .name("itemWriter")
            .resource(new FileSystemResource("report.csv"))
            .delimited()
            .delimiter("|")
            .names("applicationId", "status")
            .build();
}
```

Comment: Could you show me the example code that I should revamp when trying to write the file or any suggestions about another way to write the file in write(). Many thanks

Comment: I added an example with a suggestion.